# how to sort Immutable data

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutability, seamless-immutable

I am using 'seamless-immutable' with redux. But  i have come across a situation where I cant sort my data.

//reducer

```
export const INITIAL_STATE = Immutable({
  data: [],
});

export const updateData = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) =>
  Immutable(state.set('data', action.data));


const ACTION_HANDLERS = {
  [UPDATE_DATA]: updateData,
};
export default createReducer(INITIAL_STATE, ACTION_HANDLERS);
```

I am getting the data but when i try to sort eg: (say)arr.sort, it gives me:
The sort method cannot be invoked on an Immutable data structure.

How can i sort the data? 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: There seems to be an open issue about this https://github.com/rtfeldman/seamless-immutable/issues/182

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see your sort function being called but in order to do so you need to use the following:

```
const sortedData = Immutable.asMutable(updateData).sort(f => f.dataFieldToSort);
```